# Rotating a shapefile to North in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, rotate, grid-north

In QGIS 3.x, is there a way to rotate a 50 x 2 metre rectangle (ESRI shapefile) to exactly grid/map North (0.0 degrees in British National Grid) whatever angle it has been drawn at originally, but which has been rotated a couple of times already using the standard rotation tool? It would be also useful to have the degree shown during rotation, how can I show that on screen?

Comment: When you click on the polygon in an edit session with the Rotate Feature tool don't you get a small box in the view showing rotation values and snapping, perhaps in the upper right of the view window?